# cannot change datatype in spark dql on databricks

Tags: sql, apache-spark, databricks

I am trying to alter a column type from string to decimal in databricks using sql and have tried a few combinations and nothing is working.

%sql
Alter Table 
Alter Column  Decimal(12,2);

This is the error I receive. I have tried adding the database name in front of the table name. I tried "DECIMAL. Nothing works.

Error in SQL statement: ParseException:
mismatched input 'Decimal' expecting {, ';'}(line 2, pos 8)

Answer (score 0):

Change using SQL cast operation and overwrite it .